# How can I make my own custom OSX keyboard with autocorrect relying off a personalized dictionary?

Tags: ios, keyboard, dictionary, language, autocorrect

I really want to do this to support a minority language (Kouri-vini) that currently has zero input support but an existing digitized dictionary. I also have zero coding experience but I don't care if this takes me 10 years, I'll find a way to do it.

Comment: Exactly what language are you talking about.  If it is not yet in Unicode, things are harder.

Comment: Tom Gewecke Louisiana Creole also known as Kouri-Vini

Comment: For that you don't need either a font or a keyboard, since the normal US keyboard and many fonts do all the characters already.  All you have to do make dictionary files.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Keyboards are commonly made with the Ukelele app.  For input to work right you really need a Unicode font for the language.  Spellcheck, etc is not connected to either the keyboard or the font, but requires .dic and .aff dictionary files.  Info on how these can be made is available at

http://www.openoffice.org/lingucomponent/

Whether a custom spellcheck dictionary will also do autocorrect I don't know.

For Kouri-Vini you don't need a special keyboard or font, just the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. The main thing is the autocorrect. In the end the goal is to be able to type in Kouri-Vini and have autocorrect, by that I mean red lines under word and right click to dictionary selection drop menu.

Comment: @JDDavidson  That's not "autocorrect", just spellcheck.  Autocorrect normally means that misspelled stuff turns into corrected stuff all by itself.